# how to make the jinja2 generator comprehension work in ansible?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a list of nested dict. I would like to use jinja2 generator comprehension to create a list from it.

```
test_nested_dict_list:
  - foo:
    a:
      x: 1
      y: 2
    b: 2
  - bar:
    a:
      x: 2
      y: 4
    b: 4

- debug:
    msg: "{{(u.b for u in test_nested_dict_list if u.a.x == 1 ) | list}}"
```

this cause a error: `{"msg": "template error while templating string: expected token ')', got 'for'. String: {{(u.b for u in test_nested_dict_list if u.a.x == 1 ) | list}}"}`

Comment: So in this case you would expect `[2]`, right?

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε yes

Answer (score 2):

[JMESPath](https://jmespath.org), the JSON query language used by the filter [`json_query`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) is quite a powerful language that could help you achieve such thing.

There is actually [one example](https://jmespath.org/examples.html#filtering-and-selecting-nested-data) in there documentation that looks pretty much like what you want to achieve.

So the whole logic just lays on the capability of the query language to look for nested data in order to select a node.
So, this syntax: `` [?a.x==`1`].b `` would equal to a logic like *find all subelement having `a.x == 1`, then get me `b` out of it*.

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    test_nested_dict_list:
      - foo:
        a:
          x: 1
          y: 2
        b: 2
      - bar:
        a:
          x: 2
          y: 4
        b: 4

  tasks:
    - debug: 
        msg: "{{ test_nested_dict_list | json_query('[?a.x==`1`].b') | list }}"
```

It gives the recap:

```
PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        2
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************
localhost
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I really want to use the generator comprehension which is much easier to read and more flexible in some cases. Does the ansible support generator comprehension at all?

Comment: Well, although Ansible is Python, the templating language is Jinja. There seems to be no possibility from [there](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/), where you can even see that they are doing parallels between the filter and the corresponding generator comprehension it replace. Ansible has a list of extra filter [there](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html), but no much luck, I would say.

Answer (score 1):

Python code could be executed using `shell` module like so.

```yaml
- shell: |
    print( list(u['b'] for u in {{test_nested_dict_list}} if u['a']['x'] == 1) )
  args:
    executable: /usr/bin/python
  register: result

- debug:
    msg: "{{ result.stdout }}"
```

Comment: Off course, you can let the node do the job not only the controller, I might have forgot to think out off the box in my comment.